# CloudStack Hyper-V agentshell installer crashes

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2, cloudstack

Attempting to install the Hyper-V AgentShell on Hyper-V 2012 r2 per the instructions at:
http://cloudstack-installation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/hypervisor/hyperv.html

The installer simply crashes with the error 'unknown software exception (0xe0434352) occurred in the application at location 0x541b8384'

I also tried using the Jenkins CI build from http://jenkins.buildacloud.org/

When i run the AgentShell --install command, i get a crash dialog:

[image: unkown software exception (0xe0434352)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved, oddly, by running 'uninstall' before running install.

```
AgentShell.exe --uninstall
```

followed by:

```
AgentShell.exe --install
```

.. no crash!